# Concurrently retrieve (select) or create (insert) new row in generic SQL without conflicts

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, postgresql

I have a system which has a complex primary key for interfacing with external systems, and a fast, small opaque primary key for internal use.  For example: the external key might be a compound value - something like (given name (varchar), family name (varchar), zip code (char)) and the internal key would be an integer ("customer ID").

When I receive an incoming request with the external key, I need to look up the internal key - and here's the tricky part - allocate a *new* internal key if I don't already have one for the given external ID.

Obviously if I have only one client talking to the database at a time, this is fine.  `SELECT customer_id FROM customers WHERE given_name = 'foo' AND ...`, then `INSERT INTO customers VALUES (...)` if I don't find a value.  But, if there are potentially many requests coming in from external systems concurrently, and many may arrive for a previously unheard-of customer all at once, there is a race condition where multiple clients may try to `INSERT` the new row.

If I were modifying an existing row, that would be easy; simply `SELECT FOR UPDATE` first, to acquire the appropriate row-level lock, before doing an `UPDATE`.  But in this case, I don't have a row that I can lock, because the row doesn't exist yet!

I've come up with several solutions so far, but each of them has some pretty significant issues:

1. Catch the error on `INSERT`, re-try the entire transaction from the top.  This is a problem if the transaction involves a dozen customers, especially if the incoming data is potentially talking about the same customers in a different order each time.  It's possible to get stuck in mutually recursive deadlock loops, where the conflict occurs on a different customer each time.  You can mitigate this with an exponential wait time between re-try attempts, but this is a slow and expensive way to deal with conflicts.  Also, this complicates the application code quite a bit as everything needs to be restartable.
2. Use savepoints.  Start a savepoint before the `SELECT`, catch the error on `INSERT`, and then roll back to the savepoint and `SELECT` again.  Savepoints aren't completely portable, and their semantics and capabilities differ slightly and subtly between databases; the biggest difference I've noticed is that, sometimes they seem to nest and sometimes they don't, so it would be nice if I could avoid them.  This is only a vague impression though - is it inaccurate?  Are savepoints standardized, or at least practically consistent?  Also, savepoints make it difficult to do things in parallel on the *same* transaction, because you might not be able to tell exactly how much work you'll be rolling back, although I realize I might just need to live with that.
3. Acquire some global lock, like a table-level lock using a LOCK statement ([oracle](http://www.stanford.edu/dept/itss/docs/oracle/10g/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems027.htm) [mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables.html) [postgres](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-lock.html)).  This obviously slows down these operations and results in a lot of lock contention, so I'd prefer to avoid it.
4. Acquire a more fine-grained, but database-specific lock.  I'm only familiar with [Postgres's way of doing this](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/explicit-locking.html#ADVISORY-LOCKS), which is very definitely not supported in other databases (the functions even start with "`pg_`") so again it's a portability issue.  Also, postgres's way of doing this would require me to convert the key into a pair of integers somehow, which it may not neatly fit into.  Is there a nicer way to acquire locks for hypothetical objects?

It seems to me that this has got to be a common concurrency problem with databases but I haven't managed to find a lot of resources on it; possibly just because I don't know the canonical phrasing.  Is it possible to do this with some simple extra bit of syntax, in any of the tagged databases?

Comment: I don't see the problem if customerid is part of the external key.

Comment: If the question was **only** tagged `MySql` i would suggest using `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY`. (optionally with a `customer_id = LAST_INSERT_ID(customer_id)` to retrieve the row customer_id)

Comment: customerid *isn't* part of the external key though; that's the whole point.

Comment: @glyph Isn't a problem if you have a `UNIQUE` key on `(given_name,family name ...)` Whatever columns you are checking for.

Comment: Also note, If there is a index in place, `SELECT FOR UPDATE` will place a **gap lock** on the index preventing other session from inserting new rows with the same value(s). See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-record-level-locks.html

Comment: @The Scrum Meister: I do have a `UNIQUE` constraint on those columns; that's the problem, I get errors when doing the `INSERT` because one of a race condition between the `SELECT` and `INSERT`.

Comment: Gap locks sound interesting.  Do other databases have similar locking features?  Although that also sounds a little weird - an index affects concurrency *semantics*, not just performance?

Comment: Are you using `InnoDB`? If yes, then there **will be no race conditions**, as long as `autocommit=0` and you `SELECT FOR UPDATE`.

Comment: @glyph Yes, and it's no weird, the **unique** portion of a *unique index* affects concurrency "semantics".

Answer (score 3):

I'm not clear on why you can't use INSERT IGNORE, which will run without error and you can check if an insert occurred (modified records). If the insert "fails", then you know the key already exists and you can do a SELECT. You could do the INSERT first, then the SELECT.

Alternatively, if you are using MySQL, use InnoDB which supports transactions. That would make it easier to rollback.

Comment: INSERT IGNORE appears to be MySQL-specific, although I admit it does do what I want.  Is there a more portable alternative?

Answer (score 1):

Perform each customer's "lookup or maybe create" operations in autocommit mode, prior to and outside of the main, multi-customer transaction.

Answer (score 0):

WRT generating an opaque primary key, there are a number of options, eg., use a guid or (at least, with Oracle) a sequence table.  WRT insuring the external key is unique, apply unique constraint on the column.  If the insert fails because the key exists, reattempt the fetch.  You can use an insert with where not exist or where not in.  Use a stored procedure to reduce the round trips and improve performance.